# Seeking Drupal 7 Slideshow that allows manual controls only and no pagers

Tags: jquery, drupal, controls, slideshow, pager

I'm looking for a slideshow module that will allow me to have no pagers and use manual controls (prev/next buttons). I don't want the slideshow to advance unless triggered by the user with the prev/next buttons Can I do this with Views Slideshow?

With View Slideshow, it looks like I can eliminate pagers fairly easily, but I don't see how I can control the pace of the slideshow manually. I don't want the slideshow to advance unless triggered by the user and I don't want any thumbnails or text pagers at all.

Would this involve a change to the jquery file?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the "Transition Advanced Options" and set the "Timer Delay" to 0.

> **Timer Delay**
>   Amount of time in milliseconds between transitions. Set the value to 0 to not rotate the slideshow automatically.